# Event Hub Trigger Timing Out

Tags: azure-functions, python-3.8, azure-eventhub

I am using event hub trigger from event hub and processing them, Now when they are triggered processing of so many events leads to timeout of event hub trigger. Can I get functionality in event hub trigger to stop it after receiving a batch of events and restart on its own to bypass the timeout(I cannot increase the timeout somehow)?

Answer (score 0):

We have few versions for receiving events as V1 and V5.

•   In v1, the receive method returned a list of EventData. You would call this method repeatedly every time you want receive a set of events. In v5, the new **receive** method takes user callback to process events and any resulting errors. This way, you call the method once and it continues to process incoming events until you stop it.

•   Additionally, we have a method **receive_batch** which behaves the same as receive, but calls the user callback with a batch of events instead of single events.

•   The same methods can be used whether you want to receive from a single partition or from all partitions.

Below code will help us to achieve it without any interruptions

```
# Receive
def on_event(partition_context, event):
    print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))

consumer_client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eh_name)
with consumer_client:
    consumer_client.receive(on_event=on_even, partition_id=partition_id)

# Receive batch
def on_event_batch(partition_context, event_batch):
    print("Partition {}, Received count: {}".format(partition_context.partition_id, len(event_batch)))

consumer_client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eh_name)
with consumer_client:
    consumer_client.receive_batch(on_event_batch=on_event_batch, partition_id=partition_id)
```

For more operations have a look on the [receiving-client documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md#receiving-events)

Also, if we would like to run the function for certain time by using **max_wait_time** parameter and then close it, we can refer to this [reference code.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.aio.eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-python#close------none)